# Windows 10 глючит в virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

До переустановки системы все работало корректно, однако сейчас виртуальная система зависает и глючит. Фиксированный виртульный диск на 40 гб, лежит на SSD.

При попытке выключить систему и нажать на power, происходит это(так и зависает. сделать ничего нельзя):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Task менеджер проблем не видит, нагрузок нет.
Характеристики:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Недавно еще и не работал режим интеграции экрана, но потом оказалось, что всему виной флажок above 4g decoding в биосе, который я случайно включил. Флажок убрал - интеграция заработала, но все остальное нет. Есть идеи, что можно сделать? В биосе активированы Vt-d и,собственно, сама виртуализация.

Comment: Отключите 3D-ускорение?

Comment: Хмм, кнопка power заработала, уже достижение.Спасибо. Остальное гляну и отпишусь.

Comment: Версия VirtualBox какая, кстати?

Comment: версия  6.1.18     --эти 15 символов для коммента  бесят

Comment: Вроде все в порядке, да, дело было именно в ускорении. Хотя конечно странно, ускорение должно ускорять, а если есть нюансы должно быть предупреждение.